# Sequence em Oracle SQL com comportamento estranho

Tags: sql, oracle

Criei uma sequence, em banco Oracle, com o seguinte script:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE pcn_integra_ser_nfe
 INCREMENT BY 1
 START WITH 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 9999999
 NOCYCLE
 NOORDER
 CACHE 20
```

A mesma é utilizada em apenas UMA package, fora de qualquer loop, sendo chamada da seguinte forma:

```
   BEGIN
     -- SEQUENCE DO ARQUIVO DE NFE
     SELECT pcn_integra_ser_nfe.NEXTVAL
       INTO v_sequence
       FROM DUAL;
       pcn_salva_log_tab('diego',1,v_sequence);
   END;
```

Notem que botei uma rotina (pcn_salva_log_tab) para ter certeza das passagens. Nesse controle grava somente quando chamo a rotina, até ai tudo correto. Mas a sequence tem um comportamento totalmente errático. Ela começa normalmente com 1,2,3,4,5 e quando rodo algum tempo depois a rotina a sequence está em 20,21,22 e depois vai para 65,66,67 e assim sucessivamente.
Já revisei toda package, no banco não tem essa sequence em nenhum outro local. A mesma é chamada logo abaixo da declaração dos cursores, como abaixo:

```
BEGIN -- PRINCIPAL

   BEGIN
     -- SEQUENCE DO ARQUIVO DE NFE
     SELECT pcn_integra_ser_nfe.NEXTVAL
       INTO v_sequence
       FROM DUAL;
       pcn_salva_log_tab('diego',1,v_sequence);
   END;

   -- DEFINE O NOME DO ARQUIVO
   v_label_arq := 'A'||Lpad(v_sequence,7,'0')||'.nfe'; 

   if not utl_file.is_open(arq_saida) then  -- abre o arquivo_saida e define onde vai gravar
       arq_saida := utl_file.fopen ( ltrim ( rtrim ( v_directory ) ) , ltrim ( rtrim ( v_label_arq ) ) , 'w' ); -- w > gravar
   end if;

     --CABEÇALHO
     v_registros :=   
           Rpad('HDR',3,' ')                            || 
           Rpad(v_codigo_empresa,3,' ')                 || 
           Rpad(v_compl_empresa,2,' ')                  ||
           Rpad(v_compl_empresa2,2,' ')                 || 
           Rpad('89425888000118',20,' ')                || 
           Rpad(' ',87,' ')                             || 
           Lpad(v_contador,6,'0'); 
     utl_file.put(arq_saida, v_registros||CRLF);
     utl_file.fflush(arq_saida);
     fnd_file.put_line(fnd_file.output,v_registros);

FOR r_nfe_cabecalho IN c_nfe_cabecalho LOOP

     -- USA PARA CONTAGEM DAS LINHAS 
     v_contador := v_contador + 1;
```

O que poderia estar errado?

Comment: Publique pcn_salva_log_tab , a procedure da package pode estar entrando em alguma exceção tratada ? Lembre que sequence garante unicidade mas não integridade para evitar "banguelas" é preciso outros controles.Algumas aplicaćões como notas fiscais ou númeroscde apólice não permitem falhas.

Comment: @Motta a pcn_salva_log_tab apenas grava em uma tabela a passagem, criamos ela para nao ter commit direto na package. Sobre a exceção tratada, nesse bloco especifico são 2 querys apenas para a carga dos dados e não tem nenhum exception. Acredito que vou ter que criar uma tabela de controle se nao conseguir fazer rodar a sequence

Comment: Faz uma busca no bd all_source ou dependencies para ter certeza se nada chama a sequence e publica a sp toda se possível , cara sequence funciona desde os anos 1970. Uma busca no front-end (se for o caso). Mas não podendo haver falha nunca use sequence , ela não é efetada por commits ou rollbacks.

Comment: @Motta cheguei a criar outra sequence, continua o comportamento. Não tem front-end, é uma package que gera um txt para integração em outro ERP. Achas viavél criar uma tabela customizada ao invés de usar sequence?

Comment: Sim , desde que a numeração não possa ter falhas.

Comment: http://glufke.net/oracle/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=9806

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caso alguém passe por essa situação esdrúxula, a solução é simples, basta tirar o `CACHE 20` por `NOCACHE`. O `CACHE 20` fazia ele "segurar" 20 números a cada sessão, depois avaliei e realmente era esse o padrão. Tirando isso ele sempre vai seguir o valor do `CURRVAL` + 1

```
CREATE SEQUENCE pcn_integra_ser_nfe
 INCREMENT BY 1
 START WITH 1
 MINVALUE 1
 MAXVALUE 9999999
 NOCYCLE
 NOORDER
 NOCACHE
```

Comment: Esta eu não sabia , anotada. Farei um teste São Tomé ...